# rails button_to --- alt text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to add an alt text to a button_to tag.

Here is my button code:

```
 <%= button_to 'Reject' , reject_paper_path(paper), :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to reject this paper?' %>
```

I would like a text to appear when user does mouseover on the button.

Any suggestion ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

```
<%= button_to 'Reject' , reject_paper_path(paper), :title=> "title text", :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to reject this paper?' %>
```

You simply need to add a title option.

Hope it might of help to someone else.